# Are all positive odd integer matchs this three conditions will be a prime number?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, oeis

1. The period length of the decimal expansion of $1/n = 2^x$ and $n-1$ divides by the length.
2. The sum of $n = 2^x$.
3. The cycle length of $n = 2^x$.

($x$ is some positive integer)

(using $n=23$ as an example to define the sum of $n$ and the cycle length of $n$):

Step 1 : Get the odd part of  $23 + ~~1 $, which is $~~3$,$~~3\times2^3=23 + ~~ 1$,get $s_1 = 3$
  Step 2 : Get the odd part of  $23 + ~~3 $, which is $13$,$13\times2^1=23 + ~~ 3$,get $s_2 = 1$
  Step 3 : Get the odd part of  $23 +  13 $, which is $~~9$,$~~9\times2^2=23 +  13$,get $s_3 = 2$
  Step 4 : Get the odd part of  $23 +  ~~9 $, which is $~~1$,$~~1\times2^5=23 +  ~~9$,get $s_4 = 5$

Continuing this operation (with $23 + 1$) repeats the same steps as above. There are $4$ steps in the cycle, so the cycle length of $23$ is $4$，and the sum of $23$ is $s_1 + s_2 + s_3 + s_4 = 11$.
The period length of the decimal expansion of $1/23$ is $22$.

I checked  numbers that matchs this three conditions up to $10^7$, get this three number, $17, 257, 65537$, it seems they are prime numbers, so my question is: are all positive odd integer matchs this three conditions will be a prime number?

EDIT:

After add 'and $n−1$ divides by the length' to condition 1, I search positive odd integer from $1$ to $65537$, get this:
$17, 257, 641, 65537$, it seems they are all prime numbers.(and prime $167772161$  also is xth item of the seq)

P.S. Python code to get the the sum of $n$ and the cycle length of $n$ for $n =17$:

```
def ck(n):    
    def f(n, t):
        k = 0 
        while (t << k) < n: k += 1
        return (t << k) - n, k
    o, s, c = 1, 0, 0
    while True:     
        o, z  = f(n, o)
        c += z       
        s = s + 1
        if o == 1 or o == 0: break
    return s, c

ck(17)
# out put (4, 8)
```

Comment: Not sure the rules are clear.  What does "the sum of $n=2^x$" mean?  What does "the cycle length of $n=2^x$" mean?  The examples really are not clear.

Comment: Worth noting:  The three candidates you mention are the so called [Fermat Primes](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FermatPrime.html)  (well, excluding $3,5$).  Those are the primes of the form $2^{(2^n)}+1$.  There are no known Fermat primes greater than $65,537$.

Comment: Looks like Fermat primes - of which no biggre ones are known

Comment: Do you have any (composite) near-misses, where only two out of three conditions hold?

Comment: Try testing $4294967297$ (the next fermat number but not fermat prime).

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen I only check $2^n + 1$, need some edit.

Comment: @vepir  The order of $10$ mod $2^{(2^5)}+1=4294967297  $ is $2^7\times 3\times 17449 $.

Comment: @Vepir The period length of the decimal expansion of $1/4294967297$ is $6700416$, it seems not of the form $2^x$.

Comment: and $4294967297 = 641 × 6700417$, it is interesting

Comment: $51$ meets all three conditions, but it isn't clear to me whether we're only considering numbers of the form $2^n + 1$.

Comment: @nickgard You are right, I add 'and $n−1$ divides by the length' at condition 1.I'll do a full check later.

Comment: @lulu  also see: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/343851/question-on-odd-positive-integers-and-fermat-factors